# why is drawable.java suddenly gets a lot of error?

Tags: java, android, drawable

I started my android studio and when I ran my app, I get a lot of error comming from `drawable.java`. For example, in the following piece of `drawable.java` I got:

> NonNull, TRACE_TAG_RESOURCES, traceBegin, traceEnd, insets,
>   DENSITY_DEVICE, noncompatDensityDpi and getOpticalInsets all shows the
>   error "cannot resolve symbol" or "cannot resolve method".

```
public boolean getPadding(@NonNull Rect padding) {
    padding.set(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return false;
}

public Insets getOpticalInsets() {
    return Insets.NONE;
}

public void getOutline(@NonNull Outline outline) {
    outline.setRect(getBounds());
    outline.setAlpha(0);
}

public Drawable mutate() {
    return this;
}

public void clearMutated() {
    // Default implementation is no-op.
}

public static Drawable createFromStream(InputStream is, String srcName) {
    Trace.traceBegin(Trace.TRACE_TAG_RESOURCES, srcName != null ? srcName : "Unknown drawable");
    try {
        return createFromResourceStream(null, null, is, srcName);
    } finally {
        Trace.traceEnd(Trace.TRACE_TAG_RESOURCES);
    }
}

public static Drawable createFromResourceStream(Resources res, TypedValue value,
        InputStream is, String srcName) {
    Trace.traceBegin(Trace.TRACE_TAG_RESOURCES, srcName != null ? srcName : "Unknown drawable");
    try {
        return createFromResourceStream(res, value, is, srcName, null);
    } finally {
        Trace.traceEnd(Trace.TRACE_TAG_RESOURCES);
```

I have never even touched `drawable.java` and I did not even know it ever existed. I tried cleaning up the project but nothing has changed. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio try to go to:
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate & restart.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can guess that, you've done something wrong with you layout or xml files. Please check if all the layouts are error free.

I would like to suggest a TODO list for you so that you look for all the reasons which might create this type of error.

1. Check all the layout files for errors.
2. Check all the drawables.
3. Check if any layout file name contains any capital letter.
4. Check if any image file name contains any capital letter.

If everything is okay, then do a clean and rebuild the application.

Comment: Thaks for the suggestion!  I actually  just toyed with it a bit, added "app:showAsAction="always"" in one of my menu item, and it  somehow fixed it

Comment: Yes, that would fix that problem. As the menu.xml is a layout file too. These type of error occurs when you've some problem with the layouts.

Comment: And please accept and upvote the answer if its helpful